# Consumir Menu del sql server en un Treeview Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, freepascal, lazarus

Tengo un menu en una base de datos sql server donde el campo Pid es el id del padre que corresponde, en estos momentos no tendra nodos nietos en el menu pero para un futuro si los tendra, el objetivo es mostrar ese menu en forma de arbol en un TreeView estoy usando delphi XE4,los elementos de la tabla donde el Pid es nulo es porque son nodos padres, esta es mi tabla en la Base de datos, pero no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como hacerlo,pudiera alguien ayudarme, Gracias de Antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi blog hay un par de artículos, que aunque son antiguos te pueden servir:
[Convertir un menu en un Treeview](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/convertir-un-menu-en-un-treeview/)
[Crear un menú de aplicación a partir de texto](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/crear-un-menu-de-aplicacion-a-partir-de-texto/)

El segundo te muestra cómo generar un Menú a partir de un fichero de texto. No es exacto, pero con pocas modificaciones puedes adaptrarlo para en lugar de sacar los datos del fichero, los saque de la tabla de SQL Server.

El segundo muestra cómo convertir el menú en un TreeView.

Ambos están con código que puedes descargar, probar y adaptar a lo que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Adjunto el código de un ejemplo que he creado a partir de tu pregunta, esta enteramente basado en la información que se muestra en la tabla. Sin embargo el método que publico puede ser útil para cualquiér otra estructura de tabla que almacene un menú, se fabrica de forma recursiva para cualquier nivel de menús.

Es importante recalcar que el orden de los elementos que se van a incrustar en el TTreeView depende directamente de los resultados de la consulta a la tabla que contiene los comandos. Es decir, los elementos del árbol se crean en el orden que vienen los registros de la consulta. Se usa un parámetro del tipo TDataSet para que pueda ser utilizado con cualquier base de datos. Y una clase de Tobject en cada elemento del arbol para poder localizar el comando que se debería ejecutar al hacer doble clic (en este ejemplo) sobre los elementos del TreeView resultante.

```
type
    tElementoMenu = Class(TObject)
      Comando : String;
      //Nombre : String;
      ID : String;
    End;
...
procedure TForm1.CrearMenuDeArbol(dsOrigen: TDataSource; CampoID, IDPadre,
  CampoComando, CampoCaption, CampoVisible: String; Raiz : TTreeNode = Nil);
var
  RamaActual, PrimeraRama : TTreeNode;
  ElementoMenu : TElementoMenu;
  iIndiceImagen : Integer;
begin
  RamaActual := Nil;
  PrimeraRama := Nil;
  if not assigned(Raiz) then
    VaciarArbol;

  with dsOrigen.DataSet do
  begin
    {Para este ejemplo se usan filtros, sin embargo, dependiendo
     del tipo de base de datos se pueden utilizar otros mecanismos,
     por ejemplo, modificar la clausula WHERE de la consulta}
    Filtered := False;
    IF not assigned(Raiz) then
      Filter := IdPadre + ' IS NULL '
    else
      Filter := IDPadre + ' = ' + TElementoMenu(Raiz.Data).ID;
    Filtered := True;

    First;
    while not Eof do
    begin
      if FieldByName(CampoVisible).AsString = 'Y' then
      begin
        ElementoMenu := TElementoMenu.Create;
        ElementoMenu.Comando := FieldByName(CampoComando).AsString;
        ElementoMenu.ID := FieldByName(CampoID).AsString;
        //ElementoMenu.Nombre := FieldByName(CampoName).AsString; //Otros datos para agregar al elemento del menu
        iIndiceImagen := 0;
        if Not Assigned(Raiz) then
          RamaActual := TreeView1.Items.AddObject(Nil, FieldByName(CampoCaption).AsString, ElementoMenu )
        else
        Begin
          RamaActual := TreeView1.Items.AddChildObject(Raiz, FieldByName(CampoCaption).AsString, ElementoMenu );
          iIndiceImagen := 1;
        End;

        RamaActual.ImageIndex := iIndiceImagen;
        RamaActual.SelectedIndex := iIndiceImagen;
      end;
      Next;
    end;

    if not Assigned(Raiz) then
      PrimeraRama := TreeView1.Items.GetFirstNode
    else
      PrimeraRama := Raiz.getFirstChild;

    while Assigned(PrimeraRama) do
    begin
      CrearMenuDeArbol(dsOrigen, CampoID, IDPadre, CampoComando, CampoCaption, CampoVisible, PrimeraRama);
      PrimeraRama := PrimeraRama.getNextSibling;
    end;

  end;

end;


procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  VaciarArbol;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(treeView1.Selected) then
    ShowMessage(TElementoMenu(treeView1.Selected.Data).Comando);
end;

procedure TForm1.VaciarArbol;
var
  itm : TTreeNode;
begin
  while TreeView1.Items.Count > 0 do
  begin
    itm := TreeView1.Items[TreeView1.Items.Count-1];
    TElementoMenu(itm.Data).Free;
    TreeView1.Items.Delete(itm);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CrearMenuDeArbol(ds1, 'ID', 'PID', 'NAME', 'CAPTION', 'ISVISIBLE');
  Treeview1.FullExpand;
end;
```

[image: Ejemplo de menú desde una tabla]